Как вернуть свои серийные номера материнской платы после использования спуфа?
Пробовал:

Вытаскивать батарейку
Обновлял биос
Менял серийники через программы на те, что были на коробке.

Но ничего не получилось. Хочу добиться того, что MSI Center видел мою материнскую плату как оно было изначально.
Материнская плата MSI B760m Mortar Max Wifi DDR5

Будет полезно уточнить, какой серийный номер показывается сейчас и каким способом изначально выполняли спуф? Пробовали ли обращаться в поддержку MSI по этому вопросу?

Сейчас показывает будто у меня материнская плата на H510 - A - PRO и совсем другой серийный номер, звонил в мси сказали обновить биос и если не поможет заново обращаться. Спуф использовал тот что купил в интернете , продавец якобы говорит что это влияет только на визуал и что уже нельзя ничего сделать.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/25377316/13754729 => может поможет (но по-моему это временное решение) ?  // сказали обновить биос и если не поможет заново обращаться => поэтому наверняка лучше наверно через них
